# Telerik Editor : contenteditable="true" being inserted in the body tag

Tags: html, telerik, wysiwyg

We use the Telerik Editor in our application. For reasons unknown (we've tried a ton of different scenarios obviously) contenteditable="true" is being inserted in the body tag of the  html it's generating every now and then. We've tried pretty much everything and can't get it to replicated.

We've look through our code and asked Telerik to look through theirs without any look. In their forums it seems that other customer is seeing the same thing and also hasn't been able to pinpoint it.

Any ideas or possible sources?

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing the same issue with some of our users but we cannot replicate in our QA environment.  We think it might have something to do with insert from word with chrome.

We try to strip it out when we save (hack):

```
string EditorText = this.RadEditor1.Content;
EditorText = EditorText.Replace("contenteditable=\"true\"", "");
EditorText = EditorText.Replace("contenteditable='true'", "");
```

Comment: Yes an inelegant but effective workaround = hackaround.  Waiting for someone to reproduce this error so it can be fixed better.